# Change pptx language encoding

Tags: powerpoint

I came across the neat little R package `slidex()` to convert pptx to rmd. However, it does only support "en-US" language encoding.

How do I change the language encoding of an existing .pptx file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language tags are scattered all over a PowerPoint file. There are add-ins that can do a pretty thorough job: [PPTools LanguageSelector](http://www.pptools.com/languageselector/index.html)

Personally, I prefer to change the file ending to .Zip, expand the file and use a text editor like NotePad++ to find and replace all language tags (you're looking for tags like **lang="en-US"**), then rezip. The default Windows Zip utility is not the best for this, it adds a top-level folder that PowerPoint can't parse. WinZip and 7-Zip are better.

If you're using PowerPoint for Windows, save the file as a **PowerPoint XML Presentation (*.xml)**. Do the find and replace on that, then resave as a normal presentation. That avoids the unzip/rezip issue.